# Is this true $\exists x\forall y (x + y > 8)$

Tags: set-theory

$U = \begin{Bmatrix}
 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 
\end{Bmatrix}$

Is this true? $\exists x\forall y (x + y > 8)$

My guess is yes? My thinking is that yes, there is atleast one x, 8, that makes every other element added bigger than 8? What do you guys think?

Comment: What is set $U$ for?  Are $x$ and $y$ supposed to be elements of $U$?

Comment: First you have to ask, true where? In U? If so, then what is $5 + 8$? It can't be equal to $13$, because it is not in your universe $U$. So now you have to define $+: U \times U \rightarrow U$. However if you change your formula to $\exists x \in U \forall y \in U( x + y \gt 8)$ where $+$ here is the regular addition on the natural numbers, you can ask does ZFC prove this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you pick $x=8$. And then:
$$\text{y=1: }8+1>8$$
$$\text{y=2: }8+2>8$$
$$\text{y=3: }8+3>8$$
$$\text{y=4: }8+4>8$$
$$\text{y=5: }8+5>8$$
$$\text{y=6: }8+6>8$$
$$\text{y=7: }8+7>8$$
$$\text{y=8: }8+8>8$$
So the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks I will accept your answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

It is true: take $x=8$, then we have $x+y>8$ for all $y \in U.$